# Which chapters from the manga that haven't been made as anime yet in "Detective Conan"?

Tags: detective-conan

I watched all episodes of *Detective Conan* anime, and I want list of manga chapters that haven't been made as anime yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this list](http://www.detectiveconanworld.com/wiki/Anime#Manga_chapters_not_yet_scheduled_to_animate) the anime adaptation of chapter 975-980 is scheduled to air in the next four weeks (March 3, March 10, March 17 and March 24), while chapter 984 and above are not scheduled as animation yet.

To go the other way around as of now the following manga chapters have aired as anime:

- Everything up to chapter 974
- Chapters between ch. 981 and 983

*Note: My answer shows the state of releases on Fepruary 28, 2018. I'm also assuming the asker has watched every episode released as of this date, so up to episode 893.*